# Saving docx to a folder in project directory

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnd9L.png)

I am trying to save created `docx` document into folder `ResumeTemplates`, but the program tells me that there's no such file or directory. Anyone know what I am doing wrong in writing the directory? I'm not familiar with a specific notation for file paths, but I don't see why a document can't be saved in this folder.

Comment: Do not provide text as image.

Answer (score 0):

Change path to

```
ResumeTemplates/random.docx
```

As your's path starts from the `root` directory and it's unlikely to be true (unless you're using Unix system and `CONVERLETTER` is in the `root`). So a simple change to a relative path should be enough to fix the issue.

Comment: @Itération122442, because OP's path is from the `root` directory and it's unlikely to be true (unless `CONVERLETTER` is in the `root`). So a simple change to a relative path should be enough to fix the issue.